# Some questions on python (files)

Tags: python, algorithm, file

I'm new here and I'm also new to python. I would like to get your help, please.

```
def lines(path, prefix):
  funf = open(path, 'r')
  dictionary = {}
  for lines in funf:
     word = lines.split()
     a_word = (word[0])
     dictionary[a_word] = dictionary.get(a_word, 0) + 1
  if prefix != word[0]:
     return 0
  else:
     return dictionary[prefix]
  funf.close()
```

when I run this:

```
    inpath = "filetext1.txt"
    print(lines(inpath,"But"))
```

and I get this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:...\...\....py", line 29, in <module>
 print(lines(inpath,"This"))
 File "C:...\...\....py", line 11, 
 in lines
if prefix != word[0]:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word' referenced before assignment
```

What is the problem, how can I change it so it would be better?
I'm asking for ideas and options (**but please, without changing more things in the code... It has to be something like this structure!!!**

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that the error refers to a variable `words`, but the line of code in the traceback doesn't have any such variable, is a very strong clue that you've edited (and saved) your code after starting the program. Can you run it again and see if you get the same error?

Comment: Also, as posted here, your indentation is invalid to the point where it won't even run. And it seems possible that the actually problem could be an indentation error (is the `if prefix != word[0]` really outside of the `loop`? If so, did you really mean to only look at the words of the last line? If so, what do you want to happen if the file is empty?), that makes it very hard to debug.

Comment: but word is the split of line. I can't do it outside the for loop...

Comment: @Velox: First, Python doesn't work that way; only functions define new scopes, not every block statement. Second, `words` isn't defined in the `for` block anyway.

Comment: @user3006380: That's exactly what the problem is. If you really do have the `if` indented to the same level as the `for` itself, instead of the code in the `for` block, then you are doing it outside the for loop, which means it's doing the wrong thing for non-empty files, and raising an exception for empty files.

Comment: So what should I do? I don't know...

Comment: @user3006380: First post your actual code here, code that actually demonstrates the exception you posted. Nobody can debug your code until you do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "actual code"? That's my code...

Comment: @user3006380: No it isn't. If you paste that code into a Python script and try to run it, you will get an `IndentationError` on the second line. Do you not realize that indentation has a meaning in Python code?

Comment: @abarnert I've edited the code. If that what you mean to

Comment: Well, the code you posted above won't run. Try editing the code in your post and forma it so that it looks _exactly_ like the code in your IDE.

Comment: Sir, that's my code, I've no idead why it's not working at yours IDE.
When I click F5 I can see it runs

Comment: @Truerror: After his edit (before your comment), it _will_ run, and will demonstrate his problem (if given an empty input file).

Comment: @user3006380: Did you really copy and paste the error from your IDE? Because you should get (and I get, when I test it) `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word' referenced before assignment`. Not `words`, `word`.

Comment: Hold on, there's still another error in this code that prevents it from running (which I fixed without even noticing it): You do `funf = open(path, 'r')`, but then `for lines in f`, not `for lines in funf`. So this is _not_ your actual code.

Comment: Yes sir, but now I see that I clicked on "s" by mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clicked on "s" by mistake'? This code will not run unless there's some global variable named `f`—and, if there is a global variable named `f`, it will loop over that variable, not the file you opened.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, I see it now.

Comment: I copied it, I'm telling the truth, after all I need your help... But I pressed by mistake on some while editing in the first time, before I posted the full question.
I'm sorry.

Comment: If you're trying to count the number of words using a dictionary, I highly recommend looking into using defaultdict(int), http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Meanwhile, I can't figure out what this code is supposed to do, and you haven't told us. Are you trying to count the number of lines whose first word matches the `prefix`? If so, why are you counting the number of lines for each first word, just to use one of them? And, if you _do_ want to count up everything, why are you doing the `if`, and trying to return in the middle of the loop, instead of just doing `return dictionary.get(prefix, 0)` at the end?

Comment: Yes, you got it. I'm sorry again, forgot to mention it. I'm not sure if I understand you. I'm having difficulties to understand it that way.  Can you show me your offer please? edit your answer down there

Comment: @user3006380 He basically asked "Are you trying to accomplish A or B?", and you responded "Yes"...

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of lines whose first word matches the prefix

Comment: @user3006380: There is no way to do that without changing the structure of your code, because your structure makes no sense. Since you explicitly said you want an answer "without changing things in the code", there's no way to answer it. But I'll edit my answer to show the smallest possible change in the code.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you very much, sir. and thanks for not giving up in helping me. I know I'm "difficult"...

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `if prefix != words[0]` part is happening *outside* the loop, after the loop has finished running. So, for a non-empty file, `words` will be the split of the last line of the file. And for an empty file, `words` will never have been set, causing exactly the error you posted.

As a side note, that `for lines in f:` is looping over some global object `f`, not the file you just opened, which is called `funf`. So, I suspect that `f` is some kind of empty iterable, and you're seeing this function even when the file you wanted to look at is *not* empty. If you want to loop over `funf`, you have to tell Python `funf`, not `f`.

And you already know this isn't correct, as in this comment:

> word is the split of line. I can't do it outside the for loop

If you want to run it *inside* the loop, you will need to indent it to match the code inside the loop. In Python, block structure is based on indentation level:

```
def lines(path, prefix):
    funf = open(path, 'r')
    dictionary = {}
    for lines in f:
        word = lines.split()
        a_word = (word[0])
        dictionary[a_word] = dictionary.get(a_word, 0) + 1
        if prefix != word[0]:
            return 0
        else:
            return dictionary[prefix]
    funf.close()
```

That means you'll no longer get an error; `words` will always be defined when you use it.

There are *other* problems with this code: you're `return`ing after each line, meaning you'll never get to the second line; you're `return`ing before you close the file, meaning the file never gets closed; it's very misleading to use plural variables names for individual things and singular variable names for lists of things; it's confusing to use a local variable with the same name as the function; etc. But one thing at a time…

---

After half an hour of pulling teeth, you finally explained what you're trying to do:

> I'm trying to count the number of lines whose first word matches the prefix

There is no way to do that with this structure. Whether you do the `if` inside the loop or out, it doesn't make any sense.

The simplest way to fix it is to remove the `if` entirely. You're building up a dictionary of counts of each first word, right? So, just look up the value for the given prefix at the end:

```
def lines(path, prefix):
    funf = open(path, 'r')
    dictionary = {}
    for lines in funf:
        word = lines.split()
        a_word = (word[0])
        dictionary[a_word] = dictionary.get(a_word, 0) + 1
    funf.close()
    return dictionary.get(prefix, 0)
```

This will work, but it's incredibly wasteful to build up this whole dictionary just to get a single value out of it, and makes your code much more complicated as well… the whole thing could be written as:

```
def lines(path, prefix):
    with open(path) as f:
        return sum(1 for line in f if line.startswith(prefix))
```

Here's my filetext1.txt:

```
This is a test.
But this isn't.
But this is.
And this isn't.
```

The output should obviously be 2, right?

And both versions of my code—the "simplest fix" and the two-liner—both print ut this:

```
2
```

This works in both Python 3.3 and 2.7. If it's not working for you, either you failed at copying and pasting the code, or your input file doesn't have any lines starting with `"But "`.

Comment: Won't this still cause errors because the function name, `lines`, is also used as a variable name? E.g. `for lines in f:` and `word = lines.split()`?

Comment: @Bill: No, hiding the global name `lines` (the function) with a local name `lines` (each line in the file) just means you can't access the global value anymore. Since he's not trying to call the function from inside the function, there's no problem. (It is certainly misleading and confusing, but it won't cause any errors.)

Comment: OK, now I've another problem. It returns me the value "None"... and that's not what I've asked. What now? Why is that?

Comment: @user3006380: If `'filetext1.txt'` is an empty file, the for loop will never be entered, so you will fall off the end of the function. When that happens, Python returns `None`. If you want to return `0` in that case, you can add a `return 0` at the end of the function. However, the obvious way to get it to work with *non-empty* files (again, you're returning `0` if the first line doesn't match anything, instead of only if _no_ lines match anything) would also fix this problem. So maybe you should focus on that first.

Comment: But I've created a file named like this (not empty), and it still shows me None. Check it by yourself. Please create a file named like this and run the code.

Comment: @user3006380: Look at my last two comments on your question. I also explain it in the answer, in the part "As a side note". You're not actually looping over the file you opened, but over whatever `f` is (which you haven't shown us in your code).

Comment: f is the funf... It's my mistake, I admit it.
But what is the problem? Can you show me and guide me what to do?

Comment: @user3006380: For 30 minutes, me and two other people have been telling you we need to see your actual code to find your actual problem. Each time, you insisting that you've posted your actual code, and then you apologize and edit it and give us different code that _also_ doesn't demonstrate the problem you're actually having. There is no way anyone can help you this way. Please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to learn how to ask questions that people can actually answer.

Comment: You are right, but I've edited the post and did some changes so that's why there some mistakes. This is the code. Hope no more mistakes. Please, I really need help and therefore, there's no reason to lie or to change things that aren't like my code. Hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but still not good. I get "0" when there should be some lines that starts with the prefix...

Comment: @user3006380: You still haven't given us a complete program with and complete sample input. I'm sick of asking for it. I will show you _my_ sample input, to prove that it works.

Comment: Sir, it works, Thanks a lot!!!!!!!
What if I want to create a new file, based on the first file? What do you think about this code:

`  def reverse(input, output, rep)
    funA = open(input, 'r')
    funB = open(input, 'w')
    for lines in funA:
        for i in range(rep):
            funB.write(line)
    funA.close()
    funB.close()`

for example, if the text is:
A
B
C

then now it should return
C
C
B
B
A
A

if the rep equal to 2.

Comment: @user3006380: If you want to ask a completely new question, accept an answer here (or post and accept your own answer, if none of them are acceptable), then create a new question. Don't keep trying to drag this one out.

Comment: it's not new, it's based on this. Still to open a new question?

Comment: @user3006380: Yes, a question that asks how to do some different thing is a different question. You can (and should) put links between the questions, but you should not try to use a single question for both. (And especially not buried in a comment, especially because code in SO comments is unreadable.)

Comment: @abarnert aye sir, as you said - I do. The link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059363/python-create-file

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count the number of lines whose first word match the prefix, why not do something simple like

```
def lines(path, prefix):
    N_matches = 0
    f = open(path, 'r')
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        first_word = words[0]
        if first_word == prefix:
            N_matches += 1
    f.close()
    return N_matches
```

This could also be accomplished via less code:

```
def lines(path, prefix):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return sum([1 for line in f if line.split()[0] == prefix])
```

As @abarnert points out, an even better way is

```
        return sum(1 for line in f if line.startswith(prefix))
```